# kdb 2-way asof join (merge bid/ask tables)

Tags: kdb

I used the schema defined in http://code.kx.com/svn/kx/kdb+/tick/tba.q:

trade:bid:ask:([]time:`timespan$();sym:`symbol$();price:`float$();size:`int$())

I want to join bid and ask tables into a single quote table but can't figure out how to do it. aj[] uses only one of the table's time column but I need both time columns combined.

E.g.

bid

```
time     size price
----------------
10:00:00 10 0.05
10:00:03 10 0.06
10:00:06 20 0.06
```

ask

```
time     size price
----------------
10:00:00 10 0.06
10:00:02 10 0.07
10:00:04 20 0.07
```

The result should be:

```
time      bs bprc  as aprc
--------------------------
10:00:00  10 0.05  10 0.06
10:00:02  10 0.05  10 0.07
10:00:03  10 0.06  10 0.07
10:00:04  10 0.06  20 0.07
10:00:06  20 0.06  20 0.07
```

Is anyone using this tba schema? It is much more compact and saves on disk space significantly but I see that it's not really flexible with regards to queries. If I wanted to get an average spread per day then how I would go about it?

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried doing nested `aj`? ``aj[`sym`time;aj[`sym`time;trade;bid];ask]`` for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `aj` to achieve what you want. `uj` combined with `fills` will do the job:

```
b: 1!`time`sym`bs`bprc xcol bid / convert bid to a keyed table
a: 1!`time`sym`as`aprc xcol ask / convert ask to a keyed table
ba: `time xasc b uj a / join them and sort by time
/ forward fill the missing prices
select time, sym, fills bs, fills bprc, fills as, fills aprc from ba
```

Hope this helps.

**Update**. If you need to support multiple symbols then you should group by `time` *and* `sym` as @user2393012 suggested:

```
b: 2!`time`sym`bs`bprc xcol bid / convert bid to a keyed table
a: 2!`time`sym`as`aprc xcol ask / convert ask to a keyed table
```

and then:

```
ba: `time xasc b uj a / no change here
ungroup select time, sym, fills bs, fills bprc, fills as, fills aprc by sym from ba
```

The idea is that you apply `fills` to values within each group only, preventing prices from leaking outside symbol boundaries.

Comment: by the way, you don't need to do fills on each column. `fills select...` suffices

Comment: Thanks Igor. Does not work with sym column added, unfortunately. Fills is filling the table across different symbols as you are sorting by time. I tried to do " `time xasc fills `sym`time xasc b uj a " but it did not work either...

Comment: @derenik thats because you'd also need to key on sym as well as time. That's what the `1!` is for. So if you want to key on the first two columns its `2!`

Comment: I'm doing exactly that but prices are filled across symbol boundaries. Looks like I need to do it by each sym separately like this: {<code in the answer above> where sym=x} each exec distinct sym from bid

Answer (score 1):

You can use a union join to accomplish this.

```
q)bid
time                 sym  bsize bprice
--------------------------------------
0D10:00:00.000000000 AAPL 10    0.05
0D10:00:03.000000000 AAPL 10    0.06
0D10:00:06.000000000 AAPL 10    0.06

q)ask
time                 sym  asize aprice
--------------------------------------
0D10:00:00.000000000 AAPL 10    0.06
0D10:00:02.000000000 AAPL 10    0.07
0D10:00:04.000000000 AAPL 10    0.07

q)0!update bsize:fills bsize, bprice:fills bprice, asize:fills asize, aprice:fills aprice from `time xasc (2!bid) uj (2!ask)

time                 sym  bsize bprice asize aprice
---------------------------------------------------
0D10:00:00.000000000 AAPL 10    0.05   10    0.06
0D10:00:02.000000000 AAPL 10    0.05   10    0.07
0D10:00:03.000000000 AAPL 10    0.06   10    0.07
0D10:00:04.000000000 AAPL 10    0.06   10    0.07
0D10:00:06.000000000 AAPL 10    0.06   10    0.07
```

**UPDATE**

As the uj is on tables keyed by time and sym so the union join works with sym column too

Comment: I can't make it work with more than one symbol in the tables - fills keeps going across symbol boundaries filling GOOG prices with AAPL's.